# C# How to implement a timer delay for each user?

Tags: c#, asp.net, timer

Options for users can be turned on or off through checkboxes on the front end of a webApi Web-app:

```
Users  Func A   Func B   Func C   Func D
========================================
James    o        o        o        o
Mary     o        o        o        o
```

Clicking on a checkbox (o) calls an API end-point that updates that function setting for a user.
Users need to be sent an email when their options change BUT sending a separate email every time a checkbox is clicked isn't desireable for obvious reasons.  I know I need to implement a user-timer that delays actaully sending the user an email until, say, a minute after a given user's option was last changed.
The code called every time a function was clicked would look *something* like this:

```
private void UpDateUserNotificationsSettings(UserModel model)
{
    // Call Api endpoint to update the setting. 

    // Create a timer if one doesn't exist for this user.
    // (I need the code for this bit)
    _delayTimer = // (create if doesnt exist) new System.Timers.Timer();
    _delayTimer.Interval = 60000;
    _delayTimer.Elapsed += (o, e) => sendEmailMethod();
    _delayTimer.Start();
}
```

However, I (think I) need a separate timer for each user, and am not sure how to go about doing that.

Comment: Don't use Timers like this. You should consider implementing a back end service that, for example, sweeps the user table every minute for updates and sends an email to users that were updated between 60 and 120 seconds ago. This implies three things about the user table: 1. It has a "LastUpdated" datetime column so you know when records were last changed. 2. It has a "LastEmailed" datetime column so you know when you last emailed them. 3. Changing "LastEmailed" should not change "LastUpdated" so you don't get stuck in infinite email loops.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with AlwaysLearning. The idea is to create a background running service that runs at set intervals or always running. You can use **Hangfire** for this https://www.hangfire.io/. Hangfire provides clean way of managing background jobs. You can write a `CRON` expression for a job. There are many tools like http://corntab.com/ to generate desired CRON expression.

You will have to maintain state of Functions change in database for each user that can show what changed from previous settings. If changes made falls in the window, then notify users.

I hope this helps to help you achieve final working code.